# ASP.NET: How to pass a value to a string from a local resource?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have created a webpage called server.aspx and the related local resource file called server.aspx.resx. In the resourcefile I defined the message "{0} is required." with the key Error.

In my .aspx page I access the string:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="textboxName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Error %> ID="validatorName">
```

Now I want to pass a value, for example the name of the textbox 'Name' to the resource string, so that the errormessage is "Name is required."

Is there any possibility to pass a value to the string?

Torben

Answer (score 1):

```
string message = GetFromResourceFile();
string completeMessage = string.Format(message, "Name");
```

Comment: Okay, but this is only possibile in code behind? But how can I do this in the .aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ControlToValidate="textboxName" 
    runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="<%$ string.Format(Resources:Error, 'textboxName') %> 
    ID="validatorName">
```

Or you could try the following in the code behind...

```
validatorName.ErrorMessage = string.Format(Resources.Error, "textboxName");
```

Comment: When I try it this way, I get the error message, that the server tag is not well-formed.

Comment: Try with single quotes, i.e. ErrorMessage='<%$ string.Format(Resources:Error, "textboxName") %>'

Comment: Didn't work. With single quotes I get the error "The expression prefix 'string.Fornat (Resources' was not recognized."

Comment: try single quotes in other way, i.e. ErrorMessage="<%$ string.Format(Resources:Error, 'textboxName') %>   %> 
    ID="validatorName"

Answer (score -1):

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It should be

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="textboxName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:ResourceFileName, Error %> ID="validatorName">
```

Where ResourceFileName is the name of your resource file